# Search for an array elements in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

In my case I have an array  object `$scope.folderfiles`. I select some files from the list and I want to have the index of the selected files in the `folderfiles`. I've done this :

```
for (var i=0; i < $scope.selectedfiles.length; i++) {
    var pos = $scope.folderfiles.indexOf($scope.selectedfiles[i]);
    console.log(pos);
}
```

but I always get `-1`. When I bind `selectedfiles` I get the list I've selected which is included in my folderfiles array

example:

```
folderfiles: [{"id":135,"name":"dddd","mtime":1429881529000},{"id":136,"name":"qqq","mtime":1429881566000,"size":null}]

selectedfiles: [{"id":135,"name":"dddd","mtime":1429881529000}]
```

what's wrong ?

Comment: You should use `.filter()` and check for a unique property inside it. Can you post an example of your objects `folderfiles` and `selectedfiles` ?

Comment: Can't use `indexOf` if the objects aren't references to each other. They can look identical but doesn't mean they are the same object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indexOf` will check for two objects that occupy the same space in memory. I think what you want in this case is [angular.equals(obj1, obj2)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals) for the equality comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
folderfiles: [{"id":135,"name":"dddd","mtime":1429881529000},{"id":136,"name":"qqq","mtime":1429881566000,"size":null}]

selectedfiles: [{"id":135,"name":"dddd","mtime":1429881529000}]
```

**what's wrong ?**

indexOf compares the references of the objects when you apply it to an array of objects.

this would work :

```
selectedfiles: [folderFiles[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) if you are working with a lot of array logic

```
_.intersection(selectedFiles, folderFiles).length;
```